# How to implement IUserTokenProvider to generate token with userId inside?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication, token

I need to know userId from token which was sent user in HTTP request header.
I need to know userId before token validating, because token was encrypted by default Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserTokenProvider with user's securityKey.
Now I combine userId and generated token in one string like this:

> 57:M80hDw9MMr0ouV/4EWL7TujfGv2YYotf7bAMm4B8Rk5nN0zFKnqHZ2O923eFuGoaM6NFpGnDxtGR8lkHOUfLiUPgI6vgnwKz19sNcvGA8D1NzO/OAiQxA8y6ah+6ZXyH3La+bf9YvnvnU+URGPqwvQ==

**57** - userId, **:** - separator, **other chars** - token.

But I don't want to show userId to user.

Are there ways to hide userId inside tiken?
Can I implement IUserTokenProvider.VerifyUserToken() method that will returns userId?

Comment: You may get some idea from this http://eliot-jones.com/2014/10/asp-identity-2-0-password-reset